# Windows application with c# and access database

Tags: .net, ms-access

I have a windows application with the following specifications:

- Written in c#
- DB is ms access
- The application is on network drive.
- The DB is also in network drive.

We have been using application for the past 5 months and I had no issues but since 5/2/2018, I started getting an error about `attempting to open a database that is already opened by user Admin on machine xxx`.

This occurs only when 2 or more users try to open app and use it.

The error shows that the database is opened by admin on machine xxx - the open DB is mine, and I am sure that I did not have the DB open.

I have performed tests in various scenarios and found that who ever logs-in first to the application holds the DB which is stated in the error as the DB which is opened by the admin on machine xxx.

Can anyone please help to resolve the issue?

Comment: Please show us the code so we can look further into the issues of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Close the application and look at the location of the database, there may be a lock file (.ldb) or similar that can be deleted. delete and reopen the app. [backup all files before trying that]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did that but it did not help. I face the same issue